# How to output FormUrlEncodedContent to debug

Tags: c#, httprequest, dotnet-httpclient

I have a form post where we are sending data to an API endpoint.  Right now the vendor says that the form posts are hitting but none of the data is coming through.  Is there a way to output the FormUrlEncodedContent as a string to show the vendor?

```
var requestData = new FormUrlEncodedContent(requestModel.ToKeyValuePair());
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(apiUrl, requestData);
```

I want to output requestData to a string or json.

This is the class definition for requestModel.

```
public class LeadRequestModel
{
public string ContractFirstName { get; set; }
public string ContractLastName { get; set; }
public string PropStreetAddress { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> ToKeyValuePair()
{
    return new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
    {
       new KeyValuePair<string, string>("@@FirstName@@firs", ContractFirstName),
       new KeyValuePair<string, string>("@@LastName@@last", ContractLastName),
       new KeyValuePair<string, string>("@@Address1@@addre", PropStreetAddress),
    };
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

To output the `requestData` to a string you can read the content using the `ReadAsStringAsync` method.

```
var requestData = new FormUrlEncodedContent(requestModel.ToKeyValuePair());
var contentAsString = await requestData.ReadAsStringAsync();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(apiUrl, requestData);

Console.WriteLine(contentAsString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity I've checked how the [`FormUrlEncodedContent`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/6e36330872998c791a2c0d31b688e1bdece2451f/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/FormUrlEncodedContent.cs) works. It is super straightforward so, it could be implemented on your side as well, with only two lines of code:

```
static string Encode(string data) => Uri.EscapeDataString(data).Replace("%20", "+");
var formDataString = formData.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), 
    (sb,kv) => sb.Append($"&{Encode(kv.Key)}={Encode(kv.Value)}"), 
    (sb) => sb.Remove(0,1).ToString()); // remove & from the beginning
```

[Dotnet fiddle link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DBZ2mo)

---

I want to highlight that I would discourage you to use this in production because `FormUrlEncodedContent`'s implementation might change anytime without notice.

This meant to be used only for debugging purposes.